# I want to delete files from same directory which are not in the result of grep command

Tags: shell

I want to delete files from same directory which are not in the result of grep command.

I found `grep -L <WORD> <filename> |xargs rm`
which finds provided word in files. But I want to delete files which are not currently being used.

I am able to find out files currently being used using lsof command.

Answer (score 1):

use `grep -v` for invert the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is mentioned by Amit; do

```
grep -Lv <WORD> <filename> |xargs rm
```

the `-v` option inverts the selection.